# adding two numbers from editText in first activity and displaying the answer on a second activity?

Tags: android

Just learning and thought this would be neat to learn.

basically getting the value from editText1 and editText2, then by pressing an add button, be able to show the result answer on a second activity. I know this is probably very easy, but I wanted to learn more about how I can do simple math practice while learning the language. Thank you for your time if you respond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To get the value from an EditText
   view, call `editText.getText()` and
   save it to a (String) variable.
2. Parse the String as an Integer using
   `Integer.parseInt(str)`. Add your
   two integers together in the normal
   manner (`var1 + var2`).
3. To start a new Activity, create an
   Intent that refers to the Activity
   class you want `(Intent intent = new
   Intent(context, MyActivity.class)`.
4. Add your sum as an extra to the
   intent to share it with the new activity `(intent.putExtra("sum",
   sumVar))`.
5. Start the activity with
   `startActivity(intent)`.
6. In the onCreate() method of your new
   activity, you can call `getIntent()`
   to retrieve the Intent that was used
   to start it. Then you can call
   `intent.getIntExtra("sum")` to
   retrieve your sum.
7. You can display it in a TextView
   with
   `textview.setText(String.valueOf(sum))`