# Beginner with Android/Java - help with Intent and adding two numbers

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, parseint

i've been working on this for several days and i'm just out of ideas.
i've searched everywhere and have the book ProAndroid2.

i'm trying to do something simple (i thought) which was have two text boxes where a user enters a number in each, then pushes a button and the sum of the numbers will display.

i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628976/adding-two-numbers-from-edittext-in-first-activity-and-displaying-the-answer-on-a) on stackoverflow about doing pretty much the exact same thing and have been doing pretty good at learning all sorts of stuff, but i'm apparently missing something very very basic. i can get the text view to display a sum if i set the variables, but i can't figure out how to get user input.

the errors i'm getting are that EditText can't be parsed as in integer, even tho everything i find says to use the toString method i'm using. and i think it might be because i'm not sure how to get the app to wait to parse it until the button is clicked which is what i thought i was doing with how i have it set up. so essentially it's parsing nothing and of course that can't be parsed. ugh.

any help much appreciated. please believe i've searched and searched and read and read, i think i might be missing out on some important concept and not know what exactly to search for to get help. i've done some other tutorials but this is just really making me crazy.

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class AddNumbers extends Activity 
    {
        TextView textview;
        Button  button1;
        EditText number1, number2;


 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    //gets numbers from user
   number1 = new EditText(this);
   number2 = new EditText(this);


   button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
   button1.setOnClickListener(btnListener);
   }


   private OnClickListener btnListener = new OnClickListener()

 {

    public void onClick(View v)
   {                        


   int int1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText().toString());
   int int2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString());

   int sum = int1 + int2;

  Intent intent = new Intent(this,AddNumbers.class);
  intent.putExtra("sum",sum);
  startActivity(intent);

  getIntent();
  intent.getIntExtra("sum", sum);

  textview.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
   }
   }

 };
```

and here's my xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:text="EditText" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/number1"></EditText> 
<EditText android:layout_width="match_parent" android:text="EditText" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/number2"></EditText>
<Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
<TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.self.projectOne"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="AddNumbers"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: ok - thanks so far...i had the EditText stuff set up like that earlier today but was still getting errors so changed it back. anyways, i am now getting the following errors:                06-07 21:26:26.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(996): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 21:26:26.447: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(996): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.self.projectOne/com.self.projectOne.AddNumbers}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should get your editTexts from the content of your activity like this :

```
//gets numbers from user
   number1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number1);
   number2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number2);
```

and then on your onClick method: you dont need to start your activity because you are already on it: try this :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
   {                        

try{
   int int1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText().toString().trim());//Edited line 
   int int2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString().trim());//edited line 
   }catch(NumberFormatEception e){
     Toast.makeText(this,"try to enter a valid number", 3000).show();
```

}

```
   int sum = int1 + int2;

   //display the sum on the textView
   textview.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
   }
```

Comment: And it should have nothing to do with the Intent!

Comment: he dont need an intent , he is on the same activity

Comment: i guess i should have put my comment down here. i changed my number1 and number2 to the way you suggested and took out the stuff about intent etc. i'm still getting errors tho, but just different ones now :). guess that's something.

Comment: actually, i was just fiddling more and i'm still getting the error about parseInt. it says it can't parse "".

Comment: @Houcine. Yes, I'm just telling molly to change the question title and the tags. 
@Molly, if it say it cannot parse, most probably the String you put in the edittext is not a number (or a number larger than limit of int)

Comment: @Terrance : lool , sorry , i'm from morocco and i dont really know if molly is he or she :$ , @molly: sorry for you too ,  i will solve your problem about that error of parsing :) , see my edit , if it didn't work , plz add Exceptions that the logcat display

Comment: added errors to main post and also updated tags. i just saw your edits, Houcine - i'll try them and post back. thanks!!!

Comment: @Molly : your are welcome , we are here to help :) ,For your error , make sure that when you get your textView  u have cast it on TextView, or the cast of your EditText is wrong ,

Comment: @Houcine - Eclipse gives me this error now "The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, String, int)"  and it also says the variables in "int sum = int1 + int2" don't exist even tho they are right there in the try statement.

Comment: @molly : replace `this`with : `AddNumbers.this`

Comment: @Houcine - you are fast!!  i did some search and did change 'this' to 'AddNumbers.this'.  however, it's still giving me the same errors. also, i'm not sure what you mean about the casting my textview on TextView. as soon as i figure out one thing it's another gone wrong :)

Comment: @Molly : look , i will fix your problem and i will upload the project for u, u want to add two numbers from your editTexts , and display the result on a TextView okey ??

Comment: @molly : dont worry , i will comment my code , and it's very simple :)

Comment: @molly : this is your project, download it and reply me if it didn't work : http://www.mediafire.com/?7589v2p99qfilot

Comment: @houcine - i'm on a mac and can't open a 7s file. can you do it as a zip?

Comment: @Molly ; ok no problem , this is the zip project : http://www.mediafire.com/?2k6v2voxtlx27e7

Comment: @houcine - thank SO much! i can see now how it was a bunch of little tiny things causing me big problems.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mapped the Java `EditText` to the one in the XML.  Assign `number1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number1);` to pick it up off of the XML layout.